# How to see whole linkedlist

Tags: javascript, data-structures, linked-list

Trying to implement Queue via LinkedList, the code:

```
class ListNode {
  constructor(x) {
    this.value = x;
    this.next = null;
  }
}
class Queue {

  constructor() {
    this.first = null
    this.last = null
    this.length = 0   
  }

  getUnderlyingList() {
    return this.first
  }


  enqueue(value) {
    const newNode = new ListNode(value);

    if (this.isEmpty()) {
      this.first = newNode;
      this.last = newNode;
    }
    else {
      this.last.next = newNode;
      this.last = newNode;
    }
    this.length++;
    return this ;
  }

  dequeue() {

    if (this.isEmpty()) return null;

    const itemToDel = this.first;

    if (this.first === this.last) {
      this.last = null;
    }

    this.first = this.first.next;
    this.length--;
    return itemToDel;
  }
}
```

Everything works ok (i think), but getUnderlyingList().

Want to get something like this:

```
{"value":537,"next":{"value":201,"next":{"value":886,"next":{"value":582,"next":{"value":518,"next":{"value":42,"next":{"value":668,"next":{"value":48,"next":{"value":136,"next":{"value":674,"next":null}}}}}}}}}}
```

Instead got only:

```
{"value":674,"next":null}
```

How to see the whole chain?

Comment: keep a variable pointed to the top of it

Comment: To get the result you want, I would have expected to see a loop (or a recursive function call) somewhere in your code that enqueues some items, and I don't see one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few things you are missing here.  First, your `Queue` class is missing `isEmpty` method, which you use.  I suppose, it should have

```
isEmnpty() {
    return this.first == null;
}
```

With that added, your code works correctly. However if you execute it in the console, you won't see the json - you'll see what the browser sees, i.e. an object containing two fields, a primitive value and another object of type ListNode.  If you want an ability to print out the whole thing, you need to define your own `toString` methods - definitely on the node class, but can also be useful on the whole list.  And then print your queue as a string.  Here's the modified code:

```
class ListNode {
  constructor(x) {
    this.value = x;
    this.next = null;
  }
}

class Queue {

  constructor() {
    this.first = null
    this.last = null
    this.length = 0   
  }
  
  isEmpty() {
    return this.first == null;
  }

  getUnderlyingList() {
    return this.first
  }

  enqueue(value) {
    const newNode = new ListNode(value);

    if (this.isEmpty()) {
      this.first = newNode;
      this.last = newNode;
    }
    else {
      this.last.next = newNode;
      this.last = newNode;
    }
    this.length++;
    return this ;
  }

  dequeue() {

    if (this.isEmpty()) return null;

    const itemToDel = this.first;

    if (this.first === this.last) {
      this.last = null;
    }

    this.first = this.first.next;
    this.length--;
    return itemToDel;
  }
}

ListNode.prototype.toString = function() {
  return JSON.stringify(this);
}
Queue.prototype.toString = function() {
  return JSON.stringify(this.first);
}
```

And here's the execution log:

```
queue = new Queue()
> Queue {first: null, last: null, length: 0}

queue.enqueue(537)
> Queue {first: ListNode, last: ListNode, length: 1}

queue.enqueue(638)
> Queue {first: ListNode, last: ListNode, length: 2}

> queue.getUnderlyingList()
ListNode {value: 537, next: ListNode}

"" + queue
'{"value":537,"next":{"value":638,"next":null}}'
```

You'll notice the last command is `"" + queue` - this forces an explicit cast of `queue` to string, which implicitly calls `toString` method, which produced JSON. Thus what you see in the output is a JSON string representing your queue, and not how the browser sees the object internally.